# Probability of an element in list

Tags: python

My data

```py
List = [[[12,1,6],[12,1,6],15],[[12,2,6],[12,2,6],18]],[[12,3,6],[12,3,6],24]]
```

I have a data containing

```
number of rows having a transition from 12,1,6 to 12,1,6 is 15
number of rows having a transition from 12,2,6 to 12,2,6 is 18
number of rows having a transition from 12,3,6 to 12,3,6 is 24
```

as list 
This data is not generated.There are many other possible combinations are there in my data.The above said is the sample

I want my output to be a list having probabilities of this transition

for example

```
P1 = the probability of transition from 12,1,6 to 12,1,6 
   = 15/total length of rows/elements  in the list.(In this case it is 3)

P2 = the probability of transition from 12,2,6 to 12,2,6 
   = 18/total length of rows in the list
```

my output needs to be

```py
List =[[[12,1,6],[12,1,6],15,P1=(15/3)*100],[[12,2,6],[12,2,6],18,P2]],[[12,3,6],[12,3,6],24,P3]]
```

Have tried a lot and would be helpful if i get suggestions.

```py
def Sort(sub_li):
   sub_li.sort(reverse = True, key = lambda x: x[1])
   return sub_li

print(Sort())
```

Comment: Probabilties must be between 0 and 1, inclusive or 0% and 100% inclusive. 15 / 3 or (15 / 3) * 100 violate that.

Comment: its a sample data.I have wrritten to make clear of the logic.

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Is `[12,1,6]` the same as `[12,6,1]`? ie, does the order of the sublist matter? If not, use a counter...

Answer (score 0):

`List` had an extra `]` after `18`, so I removed it before writing this piece of code, which assumes that the length is the same for all the rows.

```
List = [[[12,1,6],[12,1,6],15],[[12,2,6],[12,2,6],18],[[12,3,6],[12,3,6],24]]

for i, value in enumerate(List):
    value.append(("P%d=%f" % ((i + 1), value[2] / len(value[0]) * 100)))

print(List)
```

Output:

```
[[[12, 1, 6], [12, 1, 6], 15, 'P1=500.000000'], [[12, 2, 6], [12, 2, 6], 18, 'P2=600.000000'], [[12, 3, 6], [12, 3, 6], 24, 'P3=800.000000']]
```